# Classes and Objects in C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

```
class anurag
{
private:
int rollno;
char name[50];
int marks;
float percen;
void percentage(int num)   
{
 percen=(num/500)*100;

}
public:
void getdata(void)
{
cout<<"\n\nEnter the name of the student:";
gets(name);
cout<<"\n\nEnter the roll no: and the marks:";
cin>>rollno>>marks;
percentage(marks);
}
void display(void)
{
cout<<"\n\nThe name of the student is:";
cout.write(name,50);
cout<<"\n\nThe roll no: of the student is:";
cout<<rollno;
cout<<"\n\n The marks obtained is:"<<marks;
cout<<"\n\nThe percentage is:"<<percen;
}};
   void main()
   {
clrscr();
anurag F;
F.getdata();
F.display();
getch();
   }
```

why the following code is not giving the desired output?

Comment: What is your question? Why are you using turbo c++?

Comment: @anurag18294: If you want people to take you seriously, say that in a visionary tone, perhaps 'turbo c++ is THE compiler! ALL shall tremble!' (I'm already trembling)

Comment: it is a very, very bad compiler - there are lots of better, free alternatives

Comment: cout << name; is better, not sure why you use gets to read string when you just as might could have continued using cin for the string. also probably better instead of using a c array use std::string and add a constructor to your code to initialize all variables

Comment: you can't use cin for multi line strings as cin do not read white spaces so i have to use gets

Comment: @anurag18294 gets doesn't read "multi line string". Anything you can do with the C I/O library you can do with C++ iostreams, with the exception of printf-style formatting, for which the c++ library provides better alternatives.

Comment: @anurag: the magic hate ball says: "YOUR MOM." So much for fortune telling. What is the desired output? What do you get instead?

Answer (score 7):

Because you have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
class anurag
{
private:
int rollno;
string name;
int marks;
float percen;

public:
void percentage(float num)
{
  percen=(num/500)*100;

}
public:
void getdata(void)
{
cout<<"\n\nEnter the name of the student:";
cin>>name;
cout<<"\n\nEnter the roll no: and the marks:";
cin>>rollno>>marks;
percentage(marks);
}

void display(void)
{
cout<<"\n\nThe name of the student is:";
cout<<name;
cout<<"\n\nThe roll no: of the student is:";
cout<<rollno;
cout<<"\n\nThe marks obtained is:"<<marks;
cout<<"\n\nThe percentage is:"<<percen<<"%";
}};
   int main()
   {
//clrscr();
anurag F;
F.getdata();
F.display();
getch();
return 0;
   }
```

I made some changes. The int num should be float. The program works fine now.
(Pardon me if the changes I've made are wrong. I'm not experienced with coding. I just tried to get rid of that error!)